# Generating pdf with images using QPrinter and Jinja2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, jinja2

I've been trying to generate a PDF that includes an image but the image does not display. I have followed this [guide](https://www.smallsurething.com/how-to-generate-pdf-reports-with-jinja2-and-pyqt/#).

There is a comment below the guide that says i should use `app.processEvents()` to include the other resources.

I also found that `loadFinished.connect` waits for the html to load before I call the print but i can't seem to make it work.

here is my code:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    ........
    btn1.clicked.connect(self.tohtml)
    def tohtml(self):
        # Random 2D list
        table = [[random.randint(0, 100) for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]

        # Some Lorem Ipsum text
        paragraphs = [p[2] for p in generate_paragraphs(3)]

        self.html = render_template("test.html", table=table, paragraphs=paragraphs)
        self.topdf(self.html, "file.pdf")

    def topdf(self, html, destination):
        self.web = QWebView()
        self.web.setHtml(html)
        self.printer = QPrinter(QPrinterInfo.defaultPrinter(),QPrinter.HighResolution)
        self.printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
        self.printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        self.printer.setOutputFileName(destination)  
        self.web.loadFinished.connect(self.print_pdf)

    def print_pdf (self):
        self.web.print_(self.printer)
```

here is my test html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <style>
        .centered {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .underlined {
             text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .datatable {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        .datatable td {
            margin: 0px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            text-align: right;
    }
</style>

</head>
    <body>
         <img src="IDSLOGO.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help or guide would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if your image is in the same directory as the html file? And if its possible, try to post the entire code, so that it includes your call to `app.processEvents()`

Comment: Yes, they are at the same directory. as for `app.processEvents()` i haven't tried it because I don't understand the comment in the guide, it says that i have to loop through `app.processEvents()`. I think there is something wrong with my `QPrinter` or `QWebView` as I have tried to replace the variable `html` with a raw html (`<html><p>test</p></html>`) and it did not display anything on the pdf. Alsoit seems that `loadFinished.connect` does not call my print function.

Comment: Try using the `app.processEvents()` line right under the `setHtml(...)` line and see what happens? I do not understand it fully either.

I do not think replacing the `html` variable with your raw html is the issue, although you could give that a shot too, by assigning your raw html to the `html` variable.

Comment: You're right, there is nothing wrong with `QPrinter` or `QWebView` It does display the html but not the images, I just need to display an image from html to pdf. Is there a plugin that i missed? also `app.processEvents()` does nothing

Comment: I was wondering, if the generated pdf leaves a blank area for the image? Or it just completely ignores the image in the HTML? While going through the documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#ColorMode-enum , I was thinking you might have to set the Color mode as well? I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, could you try adding that `app.processEvents()` line at different points in the file? For example, at the end?

Comment: Tried it, it does nothing unfortunately, I tried putting some border and image size and it does display the border but no image

Comment: It seems that I have to wait for `QWebView` to load everything before printing but unfortunately nothing I tried works

Comment: Is there a way to see what the QWebView loads as HTML before converting it to pdf?

Comment: Also, I think what he meant by "processing outstanding UI events" using the `app.processEvents()` line is that the image file has to be loaded into the HTML using the `src` attribute of the `img` element (which is a UI event). So that makes a little more sense now.

Comment: [Found](https://github.com/adewes/pdf-printer) something But I can't understand his codes

Comment: Here you can see in his template example:
https://github.com/adewes/pdf-printer/blob/master/templates/example.html 
The way he has added the image: `<img src="file://{{media_path}}/example.png" />`
Can you try prepending `file://` to your `img src` as well?

You could also try running his example to check? His example pdf shows it works, but I'm not sure what code we need to modify in yours yet. But atleast now we know its possible for sure: https://github.com/adewes/pdf-printer/blob/master/test.pdf

Comment: Well, this is weird, followed his example but the image displays as a `?` but removing the `file://` enables me to display the image but with a warning/error from cmd while generating that says: `QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files`, I think the `web.setHtml(html,baseUrl = url)` and a different jinja2 environment set up fixed it for me.

Comment: Oh wow. So its fixed then? That's great to hear. So then could you post an answer of how you resolved the issue, and tick it so that it helps the rest of the community? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks man, I'll post a detailed answer tomorrow after I studied what's what in my code. also the error on cmd bothers me so I'll look into it too. I see a lack of detailed examples regarding this matter.

Comment: Sure thing! Take your time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all credits to [adewes](https://github.com/adewes/pdf-printer) at github this is his code afterall

This is what I understood that at least solved my problem (with help of [code_byter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3623131/code-byter))

there is nothing wrong with my template and the cause is the lack of detail telling QWebView where my pictures at so adding

`url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(media_path)` then

`web.setHtml(html,baseUrl = url)`

now QWebview sees the image for me and prepares it for rendering along with my html string from jinja2
and lastly `app.processEvents()` loops through the event(rendering and fetching resouces) waiting for QWebview or the events to be finished before moving on because QWebView returns immediately without waiting for everything to render.

Here's the code:

```
jinja_env  = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("templates"))
def generate_pdf(template, filename, media_path=None, template_context=None):
    global app

    if template_context is None:
        template_context = {}                   #this is a dictionary
    template_context['media_path'] = media_path 
    #adds your os.path.abspath('your_absolute_dir_to_images') to the context dict, in the examples's case it's media

    template_path = '{0}.html'.format(template) #adds .html extension to a string ('your_template_name' + '.html')
    template = jinja_env.get_template(template_path) #gets and loads the template (your_template_name.html)
    html = template.render(**template_context)       #this executes the {{}} and {%%} inside your template
    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:                                  #prevents a crash
        app = QApplication(['--platform','minimal'])
    web = QWebView()                                  #next step after setting up the jinja part is passing the generated html to WebView
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(media_path)              #this stores a command telling webview that this is the dir where the picture is or resources
    web.setHtml(html,baseUrl = url)                   #sets your template or html to be read and the resource location
    app.processEvents()                               #this loops through the events in QApplication and waits for webview to be finished rendering the html
    printer = QPrinter()                              #after webview renders the html this part will now execute. It's pretty straightforward
    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName(filename)
    web.print_(printer)                               #now prints a pdf with image yay
```

you may not need some of the codes here to integrate it in your own code but I'll be using this because you can basically copy and paste this and it would work (if you have the dependencies) don't forget to thank [adewes](https://github.com/adewes/pdf-printer) if you find this useful and feel free to edit if there is something I understood incorrectly.

Edit:
forgot to mention that my html tag looks like this `<img src="{{media_path}}/my_pic.png" />`
it could also look like this `<img src="file://{{media_path}}/my_pic.png" />` but the latter did not work for me.